# Can't obtain hasMany relation object in loopback 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopback, loopback4

I've been trying to recover data querying with an include, my first model is "Block" and this has a "hasMany" relation to the destiny model called "Site". Well, usually this works as intended but this time it has a catch, the data is stored in mongodb with ObjectID(), so if I try to query it on robo3t or whereever, I have to put the ObjectId and inside the ID itself of the document.

I found on the loopback 4 documentation that if I'm saving or relating data which is store with objectId, I have to set the property dataType:ObjectId, but still dosnt work.

My Block model:

```
import {Entity, model, property, hasMany} from '@loopback/repository';
import {Site} from './site.model';

@model({
  settings: {
    strict: false,
    mongodb: {
      collection: 'bloques',
    },
  },
})
export class Block extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    defaultFn: 'uuidv4',
    mongodb: {dataType: 'ObjectId'},
  })
  id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  dateBlock: string;

  @property({
    type: 'object',
    required: true,
  })
  statuses: object;

  @hasMany(() => Site)
  minedIds: Site[];
  /* @hasMany(() => Site)
  minedIds: Site[];*/

  [prop: string]: any;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Block>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface BlockRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type BlockWithRelations = Block & BlockRelations;
```

My Site Model:

```
import {Entity, hasMany, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';
import {CachimbaModel} from './cachimba-model.model';

@model({
  settings: {
    // model definition goes in here
    mongodb: {collection: 'minadas'},
  },
})
export class Site extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
    mongodb: {dataType: 'ObjectId'},
  })
  id?: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  lastUpdate: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  logo: string;

  @hasMany(() => CachimbaModel)
  data: CachimbaModel[];

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    dataType: 'ObjectId',
  })
  blockId?: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Site>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface SiteRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type SiteWithRelations = Site & SiteRelations;
```

And their respective repos are as the following:
block-repo

```
import {Getter, inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {DefaultCrudRepository, repository, HasManyRepositoryFactory} from '@loopback/repository';
import {DbDataSource} from '../datasources';
import {Block, BlockRelations, Site} from '../models';
import {SiteRepository} from './site.repository';

export class BlockRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Block,
  typeof Block.prototype.id,
  BlockRelations
> {

  public readonly minedIds: HasManyRepositoryFactory<Site, typeof Block.prototype.id>;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.DbDataSource') dataSource: DbDataSource,
    @repository.getter('SiteRepository')
    protected siteRepositoryGetter: Getter<SiteRepository>,
  ) {
    super(Block, dataSource);
    this.minedIds = this.createHasManyRepositoryFactoryFor('minedIds', siteRepositoryGetter,);
    this.registerInclusionResolver('minedIds', this.minedIds.inclusionResolver);
  }
}
```

site-repo

```
import {Getter, inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {
  DefaultCrudRepository,
  HasManyRepositoryFactory,
  repository,
} from '@loopback/repository';
import {DbDataSource} from '../datasources';
import {CachimbaModel, Site, SiteRelations} from '../models';
import {CachimbaModelRepository} from './cachimba-model.repository';

export class SiteRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Site,
  typeof Site.prototype.id,
  SiteRelations
> {
  public readonly data: HasManyRepositoryFactory<
    CachimbaModel,
    typeof Site.prototype.id
  >;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.DbDataSource') dataSource: DbDataSource,
    @repository.getter('CachimbaModelRepository')
    protected cachimbaModelRepositoryGetter: Getter<CachimbaModelRepository>,
  ) {
    super(Site, dataSource);
    this.data = this.createHasManyRepositoryFactoryFor(
      'data',
      cachimbaModelRepositoryGetter,
    );
    this.registerInclusionResolver('data', this.data.inclusionResolver);
  }
}
```

I try to query and obtain the nested data from the block controller using an include as the following:
[image: Query]
[image: Result]

And my database has the following values:
[image: Block structure]
[image: Site structure]

I will apreaciate your help for real! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I didnt have to set the ids on minedIds property, I had to set it on the destinatary model property opposite to the hasMany